# how to $group array of objects and create new fields ($addFields) from those distinct results in mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

after performing a `$lookup` operation i get a array as result. Elements of this array are objects, every object has `emailID` and `Status` fields status has some possible values like SENT, FAILED, SCHEDULED.

emailID is the person who has sent the email

what i want is, **count** the occurrence above status values and create a **new fields** for that count, say
SENT: 20, ERROR: 1 like that.

emailSent field array is the result i get after lookup operation.

```
{
>! some more fields here that a want to preserve for the end result

  "company": "abc@test.com",
  "moreFields":"random",
  "emailSent": [
    {
      
      "emailID": "cecelia@tutecircle.com",
      "status": "SENT"
    },
    {
   
      "emailID": "cecelia@tutecircle.com",
      "status": "SENT"
    },
 
    {
      
      "emailID": "cecelia@tutecircle.com",
      "status": "ERROR"
    },
    {
  
      "emailID": "cecelia@tutecircle.com",
      "status": "ERROR"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried $unwind on array and tried $group by using both emailID and status also their possible combination.
but i cant create new field with count and group those fields with emailID. here is what i want.

```
        {
             "company": "abc@test.com",
             "moreFields":"are there",

             // my concerned with below array account **generation** only
             // and preserve/retain above fields


             "accounts":[
                         {
                             "_id": "sync2@klenty.com",
                             "SENT": 36,
                             "UNSCHEDULED": 0,
                             "ERROR": 1
                         } 
             // notice the _id above is email used to in group operation.
                        ]
         }
>! accounts is a array created dynamically and **with those fields** and **counted values**
```